Two dimensional recurrence with central and boundary conditions
In the course of my research, I came across the following recurrence, which I'd like to resolve.
For some $n \in \mathbb N^*$
$$
\forall m \geq 0, \forall 0 \leq t \leq 2n,\quad 
f_m(t) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text{ if }\; m=0,\\
\frac{8}{3}f_{m-1}(1) - 3f_{m-1}(0) & \text{ if }\;t=0,\\
f_{m}(t-1) - \frac{8}{9}f_{m-1}(t+1) + f_{m-1}(t) & \text{ if }\;t=n,\\
f_{m}(t-1) - \frac{3}{9} f_{m-1}(t) & \text{ if }\;t=2n,\\
f_{m}(t-1) + \frac{8}{9}f_{m-1}(t+1) - f_{m-1}(t) & \text{ otherwise.}\\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Specifically, I'm interested in a formula or asymptotic equivalent (when $n\to \infty$) for $f_m(2n), \forall m>0$. Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how to deal with it ? A good reference on this kind of recurrences would also be nice !
I've tried to use generating functions to solve this recurrence, but I'm stuck in places. The details are below (this isn't the kind of math I usually do, so bear with me).
Thank you very much !
--
I transformed my recurrence into something like this (assuming that $f_m(t) = 0$ when $m<0$ or $t<0$ or $t>2n$):
$$
f_m(t) = f_{m}(t-1) - f_{m-1}(t) + \frac{8}{9}f_{m-1}(t+1) + \frac{6}{9}f_{m-1}(t) [t=2n] + \left(2 f_{m-1}(t) - \frac{16}{9}f_{m-1}(t+1)\right)[t=n]\\ +\left(\frac{16}{9}f_{m-1}(t+1) - 2 f_{m-1}(t) + [m=0]\right)[t=0].
$$
Then using the power series $G(x,y) = \sum_{m,t} f_m(t)x^ty^m$ it holds that
$$
G(x,y) = xG(x,y) - yG(x,y) + \frac{8y}{9x}G(x,y) - \frac{8y+18xy}{9x}\sum_{m}f_m(0)y^m + \frac{6y}{9}\sum_mf_m(2n)y^m + 2y\sum_mf_m(n)y^m - \frac{16y}{9}\sum_mf_m(n+1)y^m - 2y\sum_mf_m(0)y^m + \frac{16y}{9}\sum_mf_m(1)y^m +1.
$$
And finally
$$
G(x,y) = \frac{1}{1-x+y-\frac{8x}{9y}}\left(- \frac{8y+18xy}{9x}\sum_{m}f_m(0)y^m + \frac{6y}{9}\sum_mf_m(2n)y^m \\+ 2y\sum_mf_m(n)y^m - \frac{16y}{9}\sum_mf_m(n+1)y^m - 2y\sum_mf_m(0)y^m + \frac{16y}{9}\sum_mf_m(1)y^m +1\right).
$$
My problem here (apart from the absolutely horrible rational fraction) is that the values $f_m(0)$, $f_m(1)$, $f_m(n)$, $f_m(n+1)$ and $f_m(2n)$ are not known. My only initial condition is $f_0(t) = 1$.
